# Como trabalhar com várias colunas bootstrap,

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

No bootstrap 3, existe alguns tipos de colunas col-md-xx , col-sm-xx, col-lg-xx

Minha dúvida é, existe algum padrão para ser fácil para desenvolver com todas essas colunas?

Por exemplo

"Sempre que uso col-md-4 é boa prática usar col-sm-6 e col-lg-10"

Alguma regra do tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo pensar mais no meu conteúdo do que no visual.

Isso quer dizer que a responsividade é comandada pela necessidade de cada bloco de conteudo.

Mas, observando algumas das minhas páginas, o seguinte padrão é bem comum:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

Essa razão (1, 1:2, 1:3) parece bem harmônica mas isso não quer dizer que voce deva usar isso como regra.

Comment: Interessante essa sua maneira de organizar. Pra ser sincero, eu nunca tinha visto assim. Sempre usei / vi apenas uma classe por vez. Tem alguma vantagem com relação ao uso das três em vez de só uma, já que elas são (teoricamente) equivalentes entre si?

Answer (score 0):

Eu sugiro tirar de seu código HTML a função de organizar o seu grid.

Tudo isso pode ser feito via *LESS*. Ou seja... baixe o projeto no Github e crie um ambiente para trabalhar com os arquivos *LESS* do Bootstrap.

A partir disso, basta adicionar os grids e rows, nas classes que deverão ter esse comportamento.

Exemplo:

```
.thumbnails {
  .make-row(); 

  .thumbnails-item {
    .make-xs-column(12);
    .make-sm-column(4);
    .make-md-column(3);  
  }
 }
```

Isso fará com que a manutenção e escalabilidade do código aumente muito.

Answer (score -1):

É uma boa prática analisar sua página em pelo menos 4 tamanhos, Extra pequeno(xs), Pequeno(sm), Médio(md) e Largo(lg), portanto, se quiser usar apenas uma classe por exemplo, col-md-4 significa que seu elemento (div) terá uma largura de 4 colunas a partir (mobile first) do tamanho médio.

Isso significa que que em todos os outros tamanhos menores, a largura de 12 colunas será definida pois existe um tamanho padrão que é 12.

Se não quiser que o tamanho de 12 colunas seja aplicado em determinado tamanho de tela é recomendado incluir o tamanho que achar **conveniente**.

Os navegadores atuais possuem ferramentas para ajudar a analisar sua página em diversos tamanhos. No Chrome e no Firefox basta apertar F12 para abrir uma série de ferramentas úteis para este processo.